# How to test output of all visuals in Power BI Report?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I'm looking for a efficient testing strategy for a PBI Report.

I believe that having the output of all visuals in table format — given a certain context —  could be used to compare them with the expected result.

Is there a tool that allows to retrieve - or generate the code to query - this data in an automated way?

I know that I can go visual by visual and exporting the code using the optimizer, but the report happens to have a lot of visuals that sometimes are modified, so I was looking for a less manual way to achieve this.